# UITableView Separator Inset Reference not working in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I want to inset the table view separator by 10 points from the current automatic inset so it respects the safe area etc. but when I set it in the storyboard it doesn't work as documented.

[image: Storyboard Separator Inset Settings and Reference]

[image: Separator Inset Not Reflecting the Automatic Inset]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the settings in the storyboard are not being respected.

When I added the settings in code then it worked as expected.

```
tableView.separatorInsetReference = .fromAutomaticInsets
tableView.separatorInset = .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

[image: Separator Inset Reference]